# Oracle Apex - interactive report rowspan for rows

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

Oracle Apex Express - v19.1
Is there a way for rowspan for interactive reports?

Some about this:

[This image is just example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uTBG.png)

I tried to manipulate data in a table where I have to consider that one item is valid for one sequence, and this sequence has 5 operations.